# Parse Error, unexpected '$ftp_server' T_VARIABLE (FTP file from Local Directory to server)

Tags: php, ftp, get

So I am trying to Move a file from a local directory to a remote server and I wrote the script below to do so but I can that nasty error on the Title of my Question:

## Code Here

```
<?php


//$path = "docs"; 
$path = $_GET["source"];
$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = ''; 
$results_file_dir = "results/linsyn.xml"; 
$results_rmt_file_dir = "linsyn.xml"

//FTP Details 
$ftp_server = "ftp://81.xxxx.88.xxxx";
//FTP User Name
$ftp_user_anme = "xxxxxxxx";
$ftp_user_pass = "xxxxxxxxx";



$d = dir($path);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {

    //set up basic connection
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    //login with username & password
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

  $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
  // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
  if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
    $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
    $latest_filename = $entry;

    $xml=simplexml_load_file("docs/" . $latest_filename);

    //Last element in XML
    $last = $xml->xpath("/DocumentElement/Datas[last()]");
    //echo $last[0]->BrightnessPercentage;
    $str = $last[0]->BrightnessPercentage;
    $final_string = trim($str, "%");


    //implicitly creates file
    $handle = fopen($results_file_dir, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$results_file_dir); 

    $head = "all \r\n$final_string";
    fwrite($handle, $head);

    //Turn passive mode on
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
    //UPLOAD FILE via FTP
    if (ftp_put($conn_id, $results_rmt_file_dir, $results_file_dir, FTP_ASCII)) {
     echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
    } else {
     echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
    }

    // close the connection
    ftp_close($conn_id);



    echo "File is created";



  }
}

?>
```

I really tried to find something online but no luck! I hope you guys have come accross something like this before!

Any tips or solutions are kindly appreciated - Thanks

Comment: Add a semicolon at the end here `$results_rmt_file_dir = "linsyn.xml";` at **Line number 9**